# Make UILabel larger depend on screen size (iPhone 4/5/6/6+)

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uilabel

How can I configure my `UILabel` to become greater between multiple iPhones screens (4/5/6/6+), using `Autolayout`?

See the "Label" in this example:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you want your UILabel to increase in font size when the devices have bigger screens?

Comment: @JeffLewis Yes (I m aware of `intrinsicContentSize`), but I would like the actually `UILabel` to become greater (greater size: width height)

Comment: I would reocommend doing it in code, but if in storyboard you can do it with different size classes

Comment: @RaheelSadiq Thanks, Can u reference me to an example? 10x in advance!

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pv1EHGEf884, jump to 30:00

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you set the constraints of the UILabel in the Storyboard. This will also mean you won't need to unnecessarily code anything as constraints will manage this for you.

You require at least 4 constraints per UI object to use constraints. Set the space constraints to the edges/height of the object.

On the storyboard, select your UILabel and then click on the icon bottom RHS of the view (see picture) to bring up the constraint options. Here I have set the label's distance constraints to the top and LHS/RHS of the view and here the height is fixed. Pressing the STRUT symbol it will turn BOLD orange to show its been selected.

Whatever device you are using, the object will always be set according to these constants for the distances, this also works if you turn device landscape. So if the device screen is wider, the label will stretch accordingly.

[image]

Once the constraints have successfully been added, you will see them depicted as blue lines around the label, IF the lines show up orange or red, this means you are missing constraints or you have conflicts, in which case I suggest clearing all constraints from the view and setting each object individually.

[image]

I hope this helps.